# Twitter's access tokens are not opaque

Tags: twitter, oauth

Referring to this [old april 2009 thread](http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk/browse_thread/thread/959a926d03c8400/b2e402fd41a75228) at twitter-dev; I am currently extracting the twitterid from the access token. The thread says that twitter will soon move to provide the twitterid & screenname to the callback url directly but as of today, that is still not the case. Are you still extracting the twitterid from the access token ? Is there another more future-proof way to get the twitterid/screenname given that you have the access token ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have access token, why not call [verify credentials](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-account%C2%A0verify_credentials) method which would give you the user's detailed information?